# Oracle 19c sqlplus / as sysdba asking user-name and password?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c, oraclelinux

I am installing Oracle 19c on Oracle Linux (7.6) on Microsoft Azure. I am at point where i ran
as a root user

```
$ /etc/init.d/oracledb_ORCLCDB-19c configure
```

which ended up at
[image]

```
$ ./sqlplus / as sysdba
```

where it is asking me to provide credentials, I tried SYS, SYSDBA with password "*change_on_install*" ([followed this article](http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/oracle/reset_system_pwd.aspx)), did not work, tired user oracle user-name and password, no luck. I cannt get pass through this with out this credentials. I dont remember of setting credentials in entire setup. What am i missing here? 
[image]

Comment: I don't know Unix, but - it is not that you should connect as "root user", but user who owns Oracle software, i.e. the one that installed the database. If it was not root, which one was it? As of "change_on_install", it was last used I think in Oracle 10g so ... no luck with that.

Comment: Don't do that as root, and then position your env correctly (i.e. ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, ...)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the appropriate environment variables:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-ED528602-A8AC-4FCC-AA55-A36277A66A23

You can use this script:

`$ . /usr/local/bin/oraenv`

Comment: This worked. I logged into oracle user and did `$ . /usr/local/bin/oraenv`, set the `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_SID`, i was able to connect without password. but then when I logout and login back, variables `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_SID` appears to be gone.  any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you plan log in to your system on a regular basis.  One approach is to put the required environment variables in your .bash_profile, assuming you are using bash. It's not best practice to do that for the oracle user, in case you end up running more than one database (and thus have more than one SID).

I recommend reading read the documentation on how to set your environment permanently:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/unxar/administering-oracle-database.html#GUID-A5FC7903-AA9D-4FAC-A151-A1C8DEB299DD